# CSS/Vue.js synchronize animation reset with ref value change

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, css-animations, vue-composition-api

I want to create an animation that fades between 3 states. To store these states (that contain an image and some text), I've created an array of objects (`uploadSteps`). I increment the index of this array at a specific interval to create an animation.

My problem comes with CSS, I would like to create a fade-out/fade-in effect between each step, so that the transition is more smooth. It works most of the time but sometimes, after a refresh and for the first transition, I think the CSS animation is restarted before the state is changed. I wasn't able to reproduce it constantly so far.

**What it does** => Image fade-in -> Image 1 -> Image 1 fade-Out -> Image 1 -> Image 2 fade-in

**What I want** => Image fade-in -> Image 1 -> Image 1 fade-Out -> Image 2 fade-in

If you pay attention you can see that there's kind of a blink effect at the transition between image 1 and 2. What could I do to solve this ? Help appreciated !

PS: I've included some videos to illustrate my issue

https://streamable.com/4aigjq - Animation KO

https://streamable.com/umu3nj - Animation OK

```
<template>
  <div class="screenshot-upload-processing-container">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img
        ref="imageRef"
        :src="
          currentStep ? $requireImage(currentStep.imagePath).toString() : ''
        "
        :alt="currentStep.text"
        class="image"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="centered-row">
      <span ref="textRef" class="text">{{
        currentStep ? currentStep.text : ''
      }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {
  computed,
  defineComponent,
  onBeforeUnmount,
  ref,
} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ScreenshotUploadProcessing',
  setup() {
    const stepNumber = ref(0);
    const timer = ref<NodeJS.Timeout | null>(null);
    const imageRef = ref<HTMLImageElement | null>(null);
    const textRef = ref<HTMLSpanElement | null>(null);

    const uploadSteps = computed(() => {    
      return [
        {
          imagePath: 'image1.svg',
          text: 'Text 1',
        },
        {
          imagePath: 'image2.svg',
          text: 'Text 2',
        },
        {
          imagePath: 'image3.svg',
          text: 'Text 3',
        },
      ];
    });

    const resetAnimations = () => {
      const image = imageRef.value;
      const text = textRef.value;

      if (image) {
        image.style.animation = 'none';
        void image.offsetHeight;
        image.style.animation = '';
      }
      if (text) {
        text.style.animation = 'none';
        void text.offsetHeight;
        text.style.animation = '';
      }
    };

    const updateStepNumber = () => {
      timer.value = setInterval(() => {
        if (stepNumber.value === uploadSteps.value.length - 1) {
          stepNumber.value = 0;
        } else {
          stepNumber.value++;
        }

        resetAnimations();
      }, 3000);
    };

    onBeforeUnmount(() => {
      clearInterval(timer.value as NodeJS.Timeout);
    });

    const currentStep = computed(() => uploadSteps.value[stepNumber.value]);
    
    updateStepNumber();

    return {
      stepNumber,
      currentStep,
      imageRef,
      textRef,
      uploadSteps,
    };
  },
});
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@keyframes fade {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  40%,
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.screenshot-upload-processing-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  animation: fade 3s linear;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 27rem;
  margin-top: 10.3rem;
}

.centered-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: $spacing-xl;
}

.text {
  @extend %text-gradient-1;

  animation: fade 3s linear;
  font-weight: $font-weight-medium;
}
</style>
```